# Ramda: Remember and use value

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree

I'm trying to "Ramdafy" a function and make it point-free. This is how far I came:

```js
const hasFetchedForFilterQueryString = state => {
  const filterQueryString = getFilterQueryString(state);
  return either(
    pipe(getPages, has(filterQueryString)),
    pipe(getNewlyLoadedUsers, has(filterQueryString)),
  )(state);
};

// or

const hasFetchedForFilterQueryString = state =>
  either(
    pipe(getPages, has(getFilterQueryString(state))),
    pipe(getNewlyLoadedUsers, has(getFilterQueryString(state))),
  )(state);
```

I wonder if there is a way to write even more point-free, so without holding `filterQueryString` in a variable and having to manually apply `state`?

Comment: There's always a way to make it pointfree, but in this case it's quite pointless.

Comment: Please note that monads, for instance, are designed as function application (non-pointfree) as opposed to kleisli composition, that is to say pointfree isn't necessarily more  functional.

Comment: @Bergi: I usually agree, but here I think we can make a pretty useful point-free version.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm usually with Bergi's comment.  Point-free should not be a goal on its own.  I was enamored of it when I started writing Ramda, and there are a number of functions in it designed to help make things point-free.  I rarely recommend them anymore.  I don't think that either [`useWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) or [`converge`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) often make functions easier to read or maintain.

But there is a function, [`lift`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift), known across the FP world which is helpful here.  I think of `lift` as lifting a function from the realm of values to the realm of *containers* of those values.  Thus `lift (add) (Maybe(3), Maybe(5)) //=> Maybe(8)`.  When used with functions that yield our values, it might work like this:

```
lift ((a, b) => a + b) (
  n => n * 2, 
  n => n - 1
) (5) 
//=> (5 * 2) + (5 -1) //=> 14`.
```

And that is precisely what you want to do with your function.  So here is a `lift`-based point-free version:

```js
const hfffqs2 = either (
  lift (has) (getFilterQueryString, getPages),
  lift (has) (getFilterQueryString, getNewlyLoadedUsers)
)
```

I find this more readable than either of your versions above.

I think that version rivals the simplest non-Ramda version I can come up with for readability:

```js
const hfffqs3 = state => {
  const query = getFilterQueryString(state);
  return query in getPages(state)
      || query in getNewlyLoadedUsers(state)
}
```

It's not necessarily *more* readable, though.  And it's less efficient as -- beyond the additional function invocations -- it will have to call `getFilterQueryString` twice.  But it is a readable and maintainable function.

If `lift` is still not quite clear, an intermediate format might look like this:

```js
const hfffqs1 = either (
  state => has(getFilterQueryString(state), getPages(state)),
  state => has(getFilterQueryString(state), getNewlyLoadedUsers(state))
)
```

By applying `getFilterQueryString` and `getState` to `lift (has)` we get the equivalent of `state => has(getFilterQueryString(state), getPages(state))`, and similarly with the next line.  We've *lifted* the function `has` from the realm of strings and objects to that of *functions* which return strings and objects.  We can pass `state` to these two functions to get a string and an object.

---

You can see these in action in the following snippet:

```js
// Dummy implementations just for demo.  `state` is a small integer.
const getFilterQueryString = (state) => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'corge', 'grault'][state]
const getPages = (state) => [{foo: 1, bar: 2}, {foo: 1, corge: 2, grault: 3}, {baz: 1}, {foo: 1, grault: 2}, {corge: 1, baz: 2}, {bar: 1, qux: 2}][state]
const getNewlyLoadedUsers = (state) => [{baz: 1, qux: 2}, {corge: 1, grault: 2}, {foo: 1, corge: 2}, {baz: 1, qux: 2}, {foo: 1, qux: 2}, {bar: 1, corge: 2}][state]

const hasFetchedForFilterQueryString = state => {
  const filterQueryString = getFilterQueryString(state);
  return either(
    pipe(getPages, has(filterQueryString)),
    pipe(getNewlyLoadedUsers, has(filterQueryString)),
  )(state);
};

console .log ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(hasFetchedForFilterQueryString))

const hfffqs1 = either (
  state => has(getFilterQueryString(state), getPages(state)),
  state => has(getFilterQueryString(state), getNewlyLoadedUsers(state))
)

console .log ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(hfffqs1))

const hfffqs2 = either (
  lift (has) (getFilterQueryString, getPages),
  lift (has) (getFilterQueryString, getNewlyLoadedUsers)
)

console .log ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(hfffqs2))

const hfffqs3 = state => {
  const query = getFilterQueryString(state);
  return query in getPages(state)
      || query in getNewlyLoadedUsers(state)
}

console .log ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(hfffqs3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {either, pipe, has, lift} = R                         </script>
```